# Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop server freeze after running some time after wake up

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop

1. Enable RDP (not VNC) on Ubuntu 22.04 Settings-Share
2. Log into RDP from Windows 10 machine using MS RDP client.
3. Suspend the Ubuntu machine in RDP session and the MS RDP client freeze - normal behaviour since session has endded. Close the freezed RDP client.
4. Wakeup Ubuntu machine using Wake On Lan from Windows 10.
5. Log into RDP again.
6. After some time, like 1 minute, the RDP client freeze. Close it. Then reconnect failed.
7. Disable then re-enable RDP on Ubuntu machine may fix it for this time.

How to find out what happened when it freeze?